# CQRS for commands light on logic

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

When implementing a domain with CQRS, domain-driven design and event sourcing, is it worth the effort creating a command, an event, an aggregate and a command handler for commands with little to no domain logic e.g. if I have a requirement to say, create a group, where perhaps the only requirement is to ensure the group name is not empty, is there a need to have a Group aggregate, a CreateGroup command, a GroupCreated event and a CreateGroupCommandHandler in this case?

Comment: In your specific case, where would you manage idempotency? Do you need to ensure that a group is not created more than once? Where would that occur in a simplified design?

Comment: @CPerson, Managing idempotency seems to be a concern with both the simplified and the more elaborate approach. Might not be pure DDD/ES but I tend to favour a pragmatic approach of managing this with database indexes in some fashion for situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when the domain is light on logic, so to speak, the value that comes with modelling aggregates (in-memory persistence, constraints management etc.) and  events (intent modelling, business transaction log + audit log, integration etc.) still apply. Additionally, the reasons for modelling command messages separate from event messages still apply (it's about the intent of the message and they can evolve independently). More-so, a domain light on logic, so to speak might not always remain so.

I think it might be possible, however to not have an explicit class representing the command handler. The command to aggregate mapping could be done in some other way.

However, for cases where the domain does not manage the constraints e.g. in the case where the events really are implicitly-external e.g. if the groups are managed elsewhere and simply need to be replicated to our domain, it should suffice to have only an event.

Comment: Now, I think it might be possible to just have the client send an event and the domain does basic generic validation (field lengths etc.) on this event before accepting it in which case one can dispense with the command, the handler and the aggregate and still get the other benefits for events listed here. It might seem odd to have to validate an event that has "already happened" but this is similar to how a domain will treat an event coming from outside it's bounded context anyway.

Comment: When you have an event coming from outside of the bounded context and is invalid for the receiving context, you would ideally want to handle that somehow. That process typically would involve a saga of some kind in the receiving context that would fire a command and somehow resolve the inconsistency. In that sense, you aren't rejecting it, but handling it the way you would a valid event.